# How do I convert a PowerShell datetime string from 24 hour to 12 hour format?

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

The actual line in the PowerShell script that is desired is:

```
$tsd = [datetime]::ParseExact($TSDiff,'yyyyMMddhhmmsstt',$null)
```

But the `$TSDiff` variable being used has time expressed as, without AM/PM:

```
20171023212800
```

This is a 24-hour format where 11 pm is represented by 23. It was retrieved using an FTP request which seems to only return 24 hour format strings without AM/PM.

Breaking this down, the following PowerShell command works:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("20171023092800",'yyyyMMddhhmmss',$null)
```

But the following PowerShell command does not work:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("20171023212800",'yyyyMMddhhmmss',$null)
```

The reason the second line doesn't work is clear; the hour digits are in 24-hour format, as in the `$TSDiff` listed at the beginning of this post.

Is there a simple way in PowerShell to convert the string `20171023212800` to `20171023092800PM`?

Comment: use `HH` for 24 hour time?
 `[datetime]::ParseExact("20171023212800",'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)`

Comment: Hint: 23h isn't 9PM, it's 11PM. I suggested an edit for this.

Comment: @Clijsters  Good catch! Thanks.  Missed that in the editing back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Formatting Dates and Times](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> [...]
>
> - **`h`, `%h`** - The hour in a 12-hour clock. Single-digit hours will not have a leading zero. Specify `%h` if the format pattern is not combined with other format patterns.
> - **`hh`** - The hour in a 12-hour clock. Single-digit hours will have a leading zero.
> - **`H`, `%H`** - The hour in a 24-hour clock. Single-digit hours will not have a leading zero. Specify `%H` if the format pattern is not combined with other format patterns.
> - **`HH`** - The hour in a 24-hour clock. Single-digit hours will have a leading zero.
>
> [...]

While you are converting your datetime string to a 12-hour formatted string with `hh` in the format specifier, it will convert to a 24-hour string with `HH` in it like:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("20171023212800",'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
```

Comment: I now see the command working at the prompt - thanks!  But I'm still having trouble in my script, I'm certain due to a simple syntax error.  If I do the following:  `$tmstamp = [datetime]::ParseExact($Tmstampdata,'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)` I get  a `"ParseExact" error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`   What am I doing wrong?  $Tmstampdata is set earlier in the script and `Write-Output $Tmstampdata` displays `20171023212801`.

Comment: You're welcome! 
I'd say you have a trailing space before or after your string. If you do `("20171023212801",'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)` it works. If you do `("20171023212801 ",'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)` it will throw an exception.

Comment: try `ParseExact($Tmstampdata.Trim(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)`

Comment: Your samples did not work within my script, so still unable to get the string into a variable.  It works (without Trim) if I insert a string literal, just not if I insert a variable.  I'm running the latest version of PS.  Are there any other issues that might prevent the ParseExact from working, or are there other methods to do this?

Comment: Update: I was able to see the command work within a script with a created variable, but not with the variable I have retrieved.  So, this question is answered.  I will have to post a separate question to ask for help with the real problem.

Comment: Final update: the problem inside the script was the variable type.  After converting $Tmstampdata to int64 the ParseExact command worked in the script.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
# Method 1. Use HH for 24-hour format like TessellatingHeckler proposes
[datetime]::ParseExact("20171023212800", 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', $null)


# Method 2. If you are not sure your string is
# date, use TryParse with the same format
[datetime]$dirDate = New-Object DateTime

if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact(
                  '20171023212800',
                  'yyyyMMddHHmmss',
                  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
                  [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
                  [ref]$dirDate))
{
    $dirDate
}
```